# Randomly drop a column selected from a group, excluding one

Tags: r, dataframe, random

I have the following data frame, which is going to be used as an input in a logit regression:

```
my_frame<-data.frame(y=c(1,0,1),A=c(0,1,1),B=c(1,0,0),C=c(0,0,0),t=c(1,1,1),x=c(1,0,0),z=c(1,0,1))
```

Knowing that the dummy variables A, B and C are connected through a linear equation (A+B+C=1), I need to drop one of the three before proceeding.

```
 y A B C t x z
 1 0 1 0 1 1 1
 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
 1 1 0 0 1 0 1
```

Now, here is the difficult part. I want to exclude randomly one of the columns of a group comprised by A,B,C and D, but not the one that has 1 as a value in the last row of the dataframe. 
In my example, I want one of B and C to be excluded **randomly**.

**Column D** is not present, because in this particular data frame it would always be valued 0, but it is still part of the same group of variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really get, what you mean with your last sentence about column D, but anyway, you could try this:

```
my_frame<-data.frame(y=c(1,0,1),A=c(0,1,1),B=c(1,0,0),C=c(0,0,0),t=c(1,1,1),x=c(1,0,0),z=c(1,0,1))

allRelevantCols <- c("A", "B", "C")

# Get all columns, which can be excluded
allColsToExclude <- allRelevantCols[which(my_frame[nrow(my_frame), allRelevantCols] == 0)]

for (i in 1:<how often you would like to run this>) {
  colsToExclude <- c(sample(allColsToExclude, 1))
  my_frame[, -which(colnames(my_frame) %in% colsToExclude)]
}
```

Comment: @karl_regensburger: colsToExclude takes the values 2 and 3 corresponding to column B and C. When you sample these two values in order to exclude them, what you get is the exclusion of the second or third column of my_frame ( my_frame[, -sample(colsToExclude, 1)] ). This means that you may end up excluding column A, which is the second column... Instead, what should happen is the exclusion of the third or fourth column (in this particular example).

Comment: @Bipero that's correct, thanks for the hint. I corrected it.